# Selenium messes up whenever 'chromedriver' it isn't the active window

Tags: python, selenium

(I'm working on a Macbook Pro 2020)

My selenium automation code seems to mess up whenever the chrome-driver-window isn't the 'active' window. To be more specific:

selenium needs to make a request to a website and take some data from it, but whenever I leave that chrome-driver-window minimized, it doesn't get the NEW data but instead copies what it gave me before.

I am fairly certain this isn't due to my code but because of selenium, so I want to ask: How do I allow selenium to work properly whenever the chrome-driver-window is minimized.

Here is the code:

```
for i in df2["keywords"]:
    time.sleep(1)
    search.send_keys(i)
    search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "p.total-results.js_total_results"))
    )
    except:
        print("FIRST ELEMENT NOT FOUND")
        driver.quit()
    search = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input#searchfor.wsp-search__input")
    data['aanbod'] = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('p.total-results.js_total_results').text
    df3 = df3.append(data, ignore_index=True)
    search.clear()
    print(data)
```

As you can see I'm using selenium in combination with pandas for data analysis. This is what the data looks like when I keep focus on the chrome-driver-window:

```
{'aanbod': '92 resultaten'}
{'aanbod': '167 resultaten'}
{'aanbod': '1.144 resultaten'}
{'aanbod': '102 resultaten'}
{'aanbod': '829 resultaten'}
{'aanbod': '91 resultaten'}
{'aanbod': '125 resultaten'}
{'aanbod': '225 resultaten'}
{'aanbod': '800 resultaten'}
{'aanbod': '276 resultaten'}
```

and this is what it looks like without me focussing on the window:

```
{'aanbod': '92 resultaten'}
{'aanbod': '92 resultaten'}
{'aanbod': '92 resultaten'}
{'aanbod': '92 resultaten'}
{'aanbod': '92 resultaten'}
{'aanbod': '92 resultaten'}
{'aanbod': '92 resultaten'}
{'aanbod': '92 resultaten'}
```

chrome version: mac 85.0.4183.121 (Official Build) (64-bit),
chrome driver version: mac 64 ChromeDriver 85.0.4183.87

Comment: Can you please ty explain little bit more in detail? You can use these guides as reference. [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  and [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I think that will increase the answers quality.

Comment: Which version of chrome driver you are using??

Comment: I've edited the question, thank you for the tips. I've also added which chrome driver version I'm using.

Comment: Why is the chrome window minimized? Do you want the script to run in the background while you do something else or..?

Comment: @0buz yes, exactly. I want it to run in the background so I can still work on the mac. (there's no way I'm rewriting all the code in some other language so it'll run in the background though)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your script to run in the background try using the `headless` option for chrome. It is good practice to also add `--start-maximized` when working in headless mode, as there may be cases when not having this option results in elements not getting identified.

Add these lines at the beginning of your script:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
```

You will no longer see the browser and all the clicks, navigation etc. happening, just the results in the console.